# Angular JS excel file download not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, apache-poi

I have developed AngularJS code for downloading excel file. The code works well in Chrome and IE. But not working in Firefox. The response is coming from the server without any issue. Here is my code,

```
var did = "someid";
var url = '/downloadAsExcel';
$http({method: 'POST', url: url, data:did,headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
  var blob = new Blob([data],{type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
  var link = document.createElement('a');
  link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  var fileName = headers('Content-Disposition').split(";")[1];
  fileName = fileName.trim().split("=")[1];
  var downloadName = (fileName != 'undefined') ? fileName : "DefaultName";
  link.download = downloadName;
  link.click();
})
.error(function(data, status) {
    console.log("Some thing went wrong "+status);
});
```

Any help please,

Thanks,
JK

Comment: Define "not working" - error? Firefox crashes? Universe ends? Other?

Comment: When I click the button, I should be able to see the file gets downloaded but no such thing happening. And when I debug the code, the response code is 200.

Comment: @Rama Krishna Guntuka: Where is the part where apache-poi is used here? The problem: You are creating an `A` element but do not append it somewhere into the DOM. Do `...link.download = downloadName;  $("body").append(link); link.click();...`.

Comment: Excellent, Awesome.. After appending to body it is working like a charm. Great help thanks

Comment: those who don't know the answer or how to give the answer, please don't downvote. Assh**les

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the solution after taking help from Axel.

```
var did = "someid";
var url = '/downloadAsExcel';
$http({method: 'POST', url: url, data:did,headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'},responseType: 'arraybuffer'})
.success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
 var blob = new Blob([data],{type: "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet"});
 var link = document.createElement('a');
 link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
 var fileName = headers('Content-Disposition').split(";")[1];
 fileName = fileName.trim().split("=")[1];
 var downloadName = (fileName != 'undefined') ? fileName : "DefaultName";
 link.download = downloadName;
 if(document.body != null){ document.body.appendChild(link); }
 link.click();
})
.error(function(data, status) {
console.log("Some thing went wrong "+status);
});
```